# How to achieve implementation dependend transition guards for a Spring statemachine provided in a library?

Tags: java, spring-statemachine

I provide a Spring statemachine with basic program states in a library
as base for different implementations. *Adding custom transition actions* depending on the current implementation using the basic statemachine, *seems to be easy* because of the provided [transition annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#transition-annotations).

Now I want to do something similar with guards, i.e. **provide a transition guard depending on the recent usage scenario within the implementation using the basic statemachine**.

**One idea** is to **configure a default guard** within the basic statemachine which is **implementing the decorator pattern**, i.e. it is a wrapper implementing the guard interface wrapped around another guard. As default guard wrapped a simple guard implementation is used which always returns true for 
the evaluate method.

Code snippets look something like ... first the guards:

```
import org.springframework.statemachine.StateContext;
import org.springframework.statemachine.guard.Guard;
// ... custom States and Events imports

public class GuardDecorator implements Guard<States, Events> {

    private Guard<States, Events> guard;

    public GuardDecorator() {
        this.guard = new DefaultGuard();
    }

    public GuardDecorator(Guard<States, Events> guard) {
        this.guard = guard;
    }

    public void setGuard(Guard<States, Events> guard) {
        this.guard = guard;
    }

    public String wrappedGuardInfo() {
        return this.guard.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
        return this.guard.evaluate(context);
    }
}

public class DefaultGuard implements Guard<States, Events> {
    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(StateContext<States, Events> context) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now using the GuardDecorator in the statemachine Configurer (excerpt only):

```
// ...
@Bean
public GuardDecorator guard() {
    return new GuardDecorator();
}
// ...
@Override
public void configure(
    StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, Events> transitions)
    throws Exception {

    transitions.withExternal()
        .source(States.S1)
        .target(States.S2)
        .event(Events.E1)
        .guard(guard());
    }
// ...
```

**My questions are now:**

- Did I miss something in the documentation, is there a *build-in way to do this*?
- *Any other solutions* to get an implementation dependend guard for a basic 
  statemachine provided within a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing build-in but not sure if there has to be. If you do this config based on JavaConfig, you could create default guard there and allow user to autowire optional overridden implementation

```
Autowired(required=false)
@Qualifier("myGuard")
Guard<States, Events> guard;
```

Or allowing user to override bean definition itself. If same bean is created in multiple configuration classes, latest resolved in order wins. This concept is used heavily in Spring Umbrella projects where default bean exists but is allowed to be overridden by a user.

```
@Bean(name="myGuard")
public GuardDecorator guard() {
    return new GuardDecorator();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was looking for something like this! Using a default bean is a viable option for me and probably easier to understand and maintain. I didn't know it till now. IMHO this makes some kind of spring statemachine build-in solution unnecessary as there is a more generic way already.